# Print full filenames with spaces in shell with find command

Tags: shell, scripting, find, filenames, spaces

I have a find command that will print size and filename(along with full path) of the 20 largest files on the given directory and write it into a file:

```
find ${DIR}  -type f -size +1M -exec du -h '{}' + | sort -hr|awk '{print $1","$2}'|head -20 >>files.csv
```

The problem is, there exist some files with spaces in their file names. These file names are only printed till the first space.

Ex: A file named 'hello there.txt' is printed as 'hello'

I tried setting the IFS to '\n',

```
i.e. IFS=$'\n',
```

but the problem still persists.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`, `print $1","$2` prints the first two fields separated by a comma.  The problem is that `there.txt` in `hello there.txt` is in the third column.

It seems that the only thing that `awk` is doing here is replacing the first tab with a comma.  That can be easily done with `sed`:

```
$ find "${DIR}" -type f -size +1M -exec du -h '{}' + | sort -hr| sed 's/\t/,/' |head -20
4.0M,./path/hello there.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. And awk is actually selecting required 2 columns and adding a comma in between them, since ls lists many more values and I have no need for all that.